# Multiple conditions with python decorators

Tags: python, flask, decorator

I'm trying to make unified decorators that check if resource can be requested with given permissions. Resources may be requested from browser where authorized person has filled JWT or via request by some service. For instance:

```
@check_user_jwt('resource_provider')
@check_service_id('resource_provider')
@route('/resource/') # Yes, I'm using Flask
def resource():
    pass
```

The problem is I cannot actually figure out how to make checks stop if any of decorators verified request issuer and start execution of function

Comment: Have you tried to not call decorated function?

Comment: Please share sample code of any of the decorators you have written

Comment: @OlvinRoght and if user has all the permissions to use the resource it will not be executed?

Comment: @OlvinRoght the point is that user doesn't have to have both service id and JWT. One may not have service id, but if he does have JWT with correct permissions on requested resource he should get it

Comment: @МаксимКазанцев, decorators is just chain of functions, so if you won't call decorated function - it won't be executed *(obvious, isn't it?)*

Comment: @OlvinRoght if function is not executed, there is no response to the user - Gateway timeout, 504. Moreover you didn't even try to actually read the question, otherwise you would have understood that I need to execute function in case any of decorators verified the request. And just not calling decorated function is (obviously?) not an option